# using the same id for listview

Tags: android, android-layout

Hie, can anybody tell if there is any way i can use the same id on the same layout? 
for.
e.g

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/test">
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test"/>



<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listTest">
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    "/>



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/test">
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test"/>
```

Comment: You can do something like this. But when you `getViewById()` it will return the first one only. Why do you want something like above?

Comment: possible but it must be unique. Any View object may have an integer ID associated with it, to uniquely identify the View within the tree. check the topic under id http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: I can't think of a good reason why you'd want to do this.

Comment: The purpose for Id is to uniquely identify the view. So even if you can do that technically, it is not recommended.

Comment: in which scenario you want to do this. BTW ids must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

**No** its not possible.
As stated android documentation

> Any View object may have an integer ID associated with it, to uniquely identify the View within the tree. When the application is compiled, this ID is referenced as an integer, but the ID is typically assigned in the layout XML file as a string, in the id attribute. This is an XML attribute common to all View objects (defined by the View class) and you will use it very often.

Refer to this [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

**No You can not do**..

*IDs are mean to be unique always..*

Answer (score 0):

The purpose for Id is to uniquely identify the view in the layout. So even if you can do that technically, it is not recommended considering the good programming practices.

**As per the android documentation :**

> Views may have an integer id associated with them. These ids are
> typically assigned in the layout XML files, and are used to find
> specific views within the view tree.
>
> A common pattern is to:
>
> 1. Define a view in the layout file and assign it a unique ID.
> 2. From the onCreate method of an Activity, find the view using that ID.

**Note:**

> View IDs need not be unique throughout the tree, but it is good
> practice to ensure that they are at least unique within the part of
> the tree you are searching.

**Refer**

[View in android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

[Layout in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id)

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that. If you do that the thing you want to do in your activity dynamically wont work for any of the textview.